# What is the name of the package that allows you to connect to a windows machine over RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol)

Tags: remote-desktop

I have Ubuntu Netbook with Unity installed, and I do not see the program that allows you to connect to Windows Via RDP, I would like to be able to install this functionality, anyone know what the name of the package is?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package is rdesktop, you need to run it from the terminal "rdesktop remote_hostname". If you need a GUI install gnome-rdp .

Comment: That is a pretty handy terminal trick :D

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can check out Remmina, which supports RDP, VNC, NX, XDMCP and SSH.  Rumor has it that will be the new client in 11.04.  I've been testing it and have been quite pleased.  Available via Software Center.

Comment: According to some seemingly unfounded assertions by OMG Ubuntu, the rumour has just turned into fact. (just realised how meaningless this statement is..)

Answer (score 0):

I've been happily using Remmima for about 6 months after running into various frustrations with the other options.